# Отлов исключений сразу во всей программе

Tags: python, python-3.x, исключения

Есть некая программа на питоне. Например:

```
import a
import b

def main():
    x = a()
    y = b()
    print(x + y)

main()
```

Я её даю на использование кому-то другому, кто в программировании ничего не понимает. Известно, что при определенных условиях программа может полететь. Поэтому я добавляю следующий код:

```
...
try:
   main()
except:
    print("Случилась непредвиденная ошибка. Уже работаем над исправлением.")
```

Правильно ли так делать? Или лучше добавлять много обработчиков "на все случаи жизни" в самой программе? Например:

```
try:
    import a
    import b
except ImportError:
    print("Ошибка импорта.")

def main():
    try:
        x = a()
    except:
        print("Ошибка вызова функции a")
    try:
        y = b()
    except:
        print("Ошибка вызова функции b")
    try:
        print(x + y)
    except:
        print("Ошибка сложения двух чисел. (Или чего там возвращают эти функции?)")

main()
```

Comment: А зачем? Какая этому «другому» разница, будет ли обработана ошибка или нет, если программа по итогу всё равно будет сломана и задачу не выполнит? А заменяя полноценные traceback'и на унылые принты, вы сами себя лишаете возможности разобраться в ошибке

Comment: Возможно, перехват всех исключений может иметь смысл в графических приложениях: при отсутствии консоли завершение программы из-за необработанной ошибки будет выглядеть как «молча вылетает». Если же ошибку перехватить и отобразить traceback во всплывающем окошке, то пользователь сможет увидеть её и отправить программисту на исследование

Comment: Зачем вы делаете все эти обработчики и печатаете сообщения? Что это даст пользователю? Чем хорошо что он узнает про "непредвиденную ошибку", "функцию a"? Какую  задачу вы решаете? Или ваша программа работает или нет. Второй вариант пользователю не нужен.